# How to wait for end of a coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have some code below. Delay (3000) is just replacement for a long loop (or cycle). I’m expecting that after completion of loop `println(res)` will print “Some String” and then enable `button`. But in real life `println(res)` prints an empty string and `button` became enabled at same time when I click it. 
My question is: how I can wait for end of a coroutine and only after completion of the coroutine  run `println(res)` and `button.isEnabled = true`.

```
private var res: String = ""

private suspend fun test(): String {
    delay(3000) // delay - just replacement for long loop
    return "Some String" // String received after loop
}

fun onClick(view: View) {
    res = ""
    button.isEnabled = false
    GlobalScope.launch {
        res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            test()
        }
    }
    println(res) // 1. trying to get string received after loop, but not working
    button.isEnabled = true // 2. button must be enabled after loop in cycle, but it's not waiting till end of loop
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try some thing like this:

```
suspend fun saveInDb() {
    val value = GlobalScope.async {
       delay(1000)
       println("thread running on [${Thread.currentThread().name}]")
       10
    }
    println("value =  ${value.await()} thread running on [${Thread.currentThread().name}]")
}
```

await will wait for the coroutine to finish and then run code below it

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
    res = ""
    button.isEnabled = false
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){ // launches coroutine in main thread
         updateUi()
    }
}

suspend fun updateUi(){
    val value = GlobalScope.async { // creates worker thread
       res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
          test()
       }
    }
    println(value.await()) //waits for workerthread to finish
    button.isEnabled = true //runs on ui thread as calling function is on Dispatchers.main
}
```

Comment: please do read this as well https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

Comment: Can you please explayn why I get error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its view" when I trying to change textView inside of "suspend fun test()" and how to do it correctly ? :)

Comment: suspend fun test() is running on background thread. In android only main thread can touch/update views

Comment: I'm foud it. I just put textView.text="something" inside of GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) and it's works. Thanks a lot for assistance.

Answer (score 38):

The main thing to understand here is that code within coroutine is by default ***executed sequentially.*** 
I.e. coroutine is executed asynchronously in relation to "sibling" code, but code within coroutine executes synchronously by default.

For example:

```
fun DoSometing () { 

coroutineA {
doSomethingA1()
doSomethingA2()
}

some additional code 

}
```

Corroutine A will execute async in relation to *some additional code*  but doSometingA2 will be executed after doSomethingA1 is done.

That means, that within a coroutine every next piece of code will be executed after the previous one is done. 
So, whatever you want to execute when coroutine is done, you just put at the end of that coroutine and declare context (*withContext*) in which you want to execute it.

The exception is of course if you start another async piece of code within coroutine (like another coroutine).

EDIT: If you need to update UI from the coroutine, you should execute that on the main context, i.e. you'll have something like this:

```
GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO) {

   //do some background work
   ...
   withContext (Dispatchers.Main) { 
       //update the UI 
       button.isEnabled=true  
       ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, and it good solution, but I can't make inside of coroutine - button.isEnabled=true - its cause Error. And also inside of loop I getting array, and this array must be added to listView by adapter, and creating adapter inside of coroutine also causing Error :( , without of enabling of button and adapter for listView your advice (explanation) is working very well. In my example println(res) replaced with creating adapter for listView. Here my example very simplified for easy understanding of I'm trying to get.

Comment: I've edited my answer to illustrate how you can do that from the coroutine. You're getting an error because you're trying to update UI from the background thread.

Answer (score 4):

`launch` is for situations where you don't care about the result outside the coroutine. To retrieve the result of a coroutine use `async`.

```
val res = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) { test() }.await()
```

Note: avoid using `GlobalScope`, provide your own `CoroutineScope` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm trying to do it, it says: <Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable, because of receiver type mismutch.> If I put it inside of GlobalScope.launch and start - then nothig happening. I just started to learn Coroutines, so I'm very newby, dont know how to use my own CoroutineScope.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed `GlobalScope` since I almost never use it.

Answer (score 3):

To wait for end of a coroutine from inside coroutine or from outside of coroutine use this way:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    val job: Job = launch(context = Dispatchers.Default) {
        Log.d("TAG", "1")
        delay(100) //<-- Put your long running task here
        Log.d("TAG", "2")
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "3")
    job.join()
    Log.d("TAG", "4") //<--Put the task here to execute in last
}
```

This code will print 4 in last, :
3
1
2
4

Answer (score 1):

why you don't move `println` and `button.isEnabled` inside `GlobalScope.launch` coroutine.

```
fun onClick(view: View) {
    res = ""
    button.isEnabled = false
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            test()
        }

        println(res)
        button.isEnabled = true 
    }
}
```

if you whant your code run on `main` thread add `Dispatchers.Main` as an argument.

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
   val res = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            test()
        }

        println(res)
        button.isEnabled = true 
}
```

now `println` and  `button.isEnabled` run on `main` thread and `test()` fun runs on `Default` which in real is a worker thread.

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm trying to do it I got an error -> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize

Comment: @Shkum i dont know your project is android project or not?
for android you should add this dependency or update ro latest version: 
`implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'`

Comment: Thanks, I did it before. My project is for android. At first I did project without coroutine, but app is freezing for 5-10 seconds during loop. So I'm trying use coroutine, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I'm sorry, just recheck, my coroutine library 1.0.0, I will update and recheck.

Comment: It working after update :), but I need to crteate adapter for listView together wuth "button.isEnabled=true" and I can not create it inside of coroutine.

Comment: Yes you can, just use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` for anything that needs to run on main thread. Note that you shouldn't directly update UI from business logic code, try to structure your app following the clean architecture design.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Job.join(): Unit` method to wait for a coroutine to finish before continuing with current the thread:

```
//launch coroutine
var result = ""
val request = launch {
    delay(500)
    result = "Hello, world!"
}

//join coroutine with current thread
request.join()

//print "Hello, world!"
println(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I'm tring to do it, studio says that join() can be called only from other coroutine.

Comment: You can wrap the code in another launch block