# How to wait response values in viewModelScope from two suspend functions

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, model, scope, withcontext

I have code like

```
viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
     withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
          val name = fetchName() //suspend fun
          val surname =  fetchSurname() //suspend fun
     }
     //how to wait response from name and surname to use it in another call?
    //name and surname must be async

 }
private suspend fun fetchName(): Name {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
          //db
        }
    }
private suspend fun fetchSurname(): Surname {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         //db
        }
    }
```

How to wait response from name and surname to use it in another call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your code is equivalent to

`viewModelScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO)`

Therefore everything inside your `launch` block is executed **sequentially**, because it is simply one coroutine. It means that any code in the block after

```
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ // Place it in your launch block
      val name = fetchName() //suspend fun
      val surname =  fetchSurname() //suspend fun
 }
```

will execute only after `fetchName` and `fetchSurname` complete. If you want to update some UI after it, for example, you can use

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { 
   textView1.text = name  
   textView2.text = surname
}
```

If you want to use it as a property in the view model consider using `Flow`

**UPD:** For your specific case

```
viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val name = fetchName() //suspend fun
        val surname =  fetchSurname() //suspend fun

        apiCall(name, surname) // it will execute only after name and surname are fetched
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but how can I get name and surname from this block?

Comment: @Slava updated my answer. Depends on how you want to use these values

Comment: I need to use them in api call, not for UI

Comment: @Slava you can make an API call right inside the `launch` block after `fetch` calls

Comment: like this?
        var name: Name
        var surname: Surname
        viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                name = fetchName()
                surname =  fetchSurname()
            }
            call(name, surname)
        }

Comment: @Slava I updated my answer once again. There is no need to create global variables for them

Comment: Also see this question on how to wait for coroutines completion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491707/how-to-wait-for-end-of-a-coroutine

Comment: Is fetchName() and fetchSurname async ?

Comment: @Slava they are async in relation to UI. It will not freeze UI or other coroutine. They are also async in relation to each other since `Dispatchers.IO` is probably using thread pool under the hood.

Comment: They aren't async to each other because they are called in sequence in the same coroutine (although they might be executed on different threads from the thread pool). `fetchSurname()` will not be called until the preceding line with `fetchName()` returns. Suspend functions are truly synchronous functions. It is only the coroutine as a whole that is asynchronous.

Comment: @Tenfour04 as always you have corrected me :) thanks, I actually was thinking about other IO coroutine while was writing that